# post request to Restful web service in azure function using node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, rest, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am new to the azure function and trying to make a post request to a RESTful web service through the azure function. However, I am not sure if I have the web service URL in the right place which is in `function.json` as follows:

```
"bindings": [
{
  "authLevel": "anonymous",
  "type": "httpTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "name": "req",
  "methods": ["post"],
  "route": "endpoint/{company}",
  "backendUri": "url"
},
```

Also, The following is the post method in `index.js`. It returns 505 error code on postman. can someone advise what's wrong there as I am sure there are missing bits along these lines.

Eventually, there will be data in the response for this request and that's what I am trying to see.

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
const body = JSON.stringify({
  appUser: "YAMEN",
});
const options = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization" : "Basic ******* "
  },
};

var response = "";
const request = http.req(options, (res) => {
  context.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);

  res.on("data", (d) => {
    response += d;
  });

  res.on("end", (d) => {
    context.res = {
      body: res.statusCode,
    };
    context.done();
  });
});

request.on("error", (error) => {
  context.log.error(error);
  context.done();
});

request.write(body);
request.end();
   };
 };
```

Comment: Try to use `https.request(options, function(res)` and also delete `context.done();`  from the code because latest function versions don't need it.

Comment: any link that I can reference that you think is useful to use https post request ?

Answer (score 0):

The function.json describes the configuration/bindings of your function.

backendUri is a proxy feature and I think in this case not what you want to achieve.

As I understand you, you want to call another HTTP API from inside the function, not redirect the traffic there?

To provide configuration values localy local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "myUrl": "https://somewhere-on-the-web.example.org",
  }
}
```

When you host it in Azure, set this config value in the configuration tab
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal

Within the function code you should be able to retrieve the config value:

```
process.env["myUrl"]
```

Comment: Thanks Julian, I get now where the URL goes to, but any idea though how to debug my code. there are debug messages in the code but they are not printing anything back on debig console

Comment: should be context.log() - find more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2-v3-v4-export%2Cv2-v3-v4-done%2Cv2%2Cv2-log-custom-telemetry%2Cv2-accessing-request-and-response%2Cwindows-setting-the-node-version#writing-trace-output-to-the-console